# Android form submission to ASP

Tags: android, forms, asp-classic, iis-8

Okay, weird, weird question time.  I have an Android app that submits data to the server using a form POST to an ASP page.  Well, at least it SHOULD.  I actually have 2 domains.  Let's say they are: MySite.com and MySiteBeta.com.

When I use the Android app and post to MySite.com the form data is received without any problems.  When I modify the app to post to MySiteBeta.com the form data is not received.  (No changes to the code except the domain name)  Mind you, there are no errors recorded in the page - and execution continues past where any error should have occured.  But, no form data is present.  I'm looping through the Request.Form object just to be sure, and nothing is there.  Also, if I just create another ASP page to send this form data, everything works fine.  So, it doesn't seem to be anything with the ASP page itself.

What could cause an Android app to work when posting to one domain but not another?  NOTE: The files on the server are the same.  I'm assuming it may be some sort of permissions in the ASP setup (running IIS8)?  Not sure.

Comment: Put a proxy (wireshark, Charles, etc) between the device and your server to see what is really going on over the wire and to see what differences are there between the two sites.

Comment: So wireshark wasn't much help. I can see the dns queries and the send and response, but it's a typical encoded post going out, and a 200 response coming back.

Comment: UPDATE: It seems that when the Android app sends to the production server it's receiving the request as a POST form submission, but when received on the beta server it's a GET form submission.  Any idea why the servers would be interpreting the exact same request in two different ways?  I'm really at a loss here.